# conditional formatting in excel 2010 for one letter

Tags: excel, formatting

I have four answers in a table.  "A", "NA", "SA" and "NM".  I need all four questions to be highlighted with a different color.  How do I make excel ignore the "a" in "sa" and make those two cells different colors?

Answer (score 3):

You just set up the rules:

[image]

Results:

[image]

Comment: @pnuts Hopefully he will clarify what he wants. Since he was writing about formatting with regard to the answers, I thought "questions to be highlighted" was a mistyping.